# Angularjs Bootstrap to Material

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I am changing the UI code from bootstrap to material. I am using angularjs and material 1.1.20. I do not know angularjs but would like to learn. Please see the code I need to change to angularjs material below.

I know that `md-select` does not accept ng-options, but I do not have any idea how I can change it to work with `md-select` tag.

My background is designing HTML CSS but I want to learn more js and angular etc.

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-no-pad">
  <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="LANGUAGE">Language</span>
  <select name="LANGUAGE" class="form-control" tabindex="8"
                          ng-init="LANGUAGE = null"
                          ng-model="LANGUAGE"
                          ng-options="language.KEYID as language.DESC for language in languages">
 <option value="">-Select One-</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

js:

```
 dataService.getAll('language').then(function(data) {
    $scope.languages = data.data;
  });
```

I want it to work as an angularjs material dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `ng-repeat` on `<md-option>`. Check the snippet below.

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial'])
  .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.languages = [{
      desc: 'English',
      keyid: 1,
      position: 5
    }, {
      desc: 'Italian',
      keyid: 2,
      position: null
    }, {
      desc: 'Spanish',
      keyid: 3,
      position: 43
    }, {
      desc: 'Malayalam',
      keyid: 4,
      position: 8
    }];
  });
```

```css
md-input-container {
  min-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular-aria.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-cloak ng-controller="AppCtrl as ctrl">
  <md-input-container>
    <label>Languages</label>
    <md-select ng-model="languageSelected">
      <md-option ng-repeat="item in languages" ng-value="item.keyid">
        {{ item.desc }}
      </md-option>
    </md-select>
  </md-input-container>
  <div>Your selection: {{ languageSelected || '--' }}</div>
  <div ng-repeat="item in languages" ng-if="item.keyid == languageSelected">
    <div>desc: {{ item.desc || '--' }}</div>
    <div>position: {{ item.position || '--' }}</div>
    <div>keyid: {{ item.keyid || '--' }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try to implement this asap.

Comment: I have not gotten it. Please realize I am new. Please see: https://ibb.co/SsN1QKQ <md-input-container>
   <label>Language</label>
          <md-select name="LANGUAGE" tabindex="8" ng-model="LANGUAGE">
                 <md-option ng-repeat="data in languages">{{data}}</md-option>
         </md-select>
</md-input-container>                      
                                                         
    dataService.getAll('language').then(function(data) {
    $scope.languages = data.data;
  });

Comment: I am not able to view the screenshot. Any other means that you can share it? What is the error ?

Comment: "KEYID":30,"DESC":"Korean","POSITION":null <--that is what is repeating, the different languages but the entire string.

Comment: okay, `KEYID` is the drop-down value, `Korean` is the text to be shown, where does `POSITION` fit in the drop-down? (FYI: I am able to see the screen show now)

Comment: Only the text should be shown, I am not sure of the position value at this time. Original Dropdown: https://ibb.co/jMXB7Kt (bootstrap)

Comment: This works! You have helped me so much with my programming journey! I did use ng-value="item.DESC" instead of ng-value="item.keyid"?

Comment: Perfect, it’s awesome to be a coder, isnt it? :D and yeah, the value depends on what you need when a entry is selected. You can give desc or keyid as per your requirement. Please feel free to accept this answer if you think this has solved your issue. It may help somine else as well.